# doctrine - Inserting records in many to many relationship table

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, many-to-many

I have two models `Property` and `Amenity` the relationship between them is many to many. the reference class is `PropertyAmenity` when i want to insert single record into one model it is easy for me.

to insert into `Property`

```
$property = new Property();
$property->serial = 'SER09088';
$property->title = 'Some title';
$property->save();
```

and to insert record into Amenity it is

```
$amenity = new Amenity();
$amenity->name = 'Swimming Pool';
$amenity->save();
```

what i want to do is add existing amenities to `Property` the record of which holds in reference class `PropertyAmenity` for example something like.

```
$property = new Property();
$property->serial = 'SER09088';
$property->title = 'Some title';
$property->PropertyAmenity->amenity_id[] = 1;
$property->save();
```

when i try the above code it gives me following exception

> Add is not supported for PropertyAmenity

the situation is i gather collective information from a form, from a user. for example a user inputs all the value related to `Property` and select existing `Multiple Amenities` from the form and submit. i need to save Property in property table and the selected amenities in `property_amenity` table which consist of two columns `property_id` and `amenity_id`, how do insert this value in doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around a little bit, i found the solution myself and as expected, it is so easy to implement. the only change i had to do was.

From this

```
$property->PropertyAmenity->amenity_id[] = 1;
```

To

```
$property->PropertyAmenity[]->amenity_id = 1;
$property->PropertyAmenity[]->amenity_id = 3;
$property->PropertyAmenity[]->amenity_id = 5;
```

and it works, hope it helps someone :)